# Powershell Script to robocopy

Tags: powershell, active-directory, robocopy

I am trying to write a script that allows me to robocopy active directory users from one path to another, amongst other things. I have managed to create a csv document that lists the usernames and homedirectory of those that I want to move. What I am trying to do next is to:

Read through the users I want to move, robocopy from old home to new home, configure the permissions, change home drive path for the AD Account, set the old home to ready only for users.

So far I have been able to produce the following script which simply moves one user to a new destination:

```
$csv = "c:\AllUsers.csv"
$log = "c:\B\Home_robocopy2014.log"

Import-Csv $csv | % { $_.username }| % {
  $src = "\\filearch1\users\johnson1"
  $dst = "C:\B\"

  robocopy "$src" "$dst" /s /e /MIR /COPY:DATS /log+:"$log" /R:1 /W:5

}
```

This seems to work ok but I am obviously wanting to add to this by looping through the subsetlist_of_users, setting the old home path to read only, configure permissions and changing the home drive path for each AD Account.

Any assistance would be appreciated on this. Many thanks

Comment: `Import-Csv $csv | % { $_.username }| % {` - this is a problem. Essentially you're importing the CSV, and for every item you're outputting the username and sending that to a single robocopy command which does something with johnson. Add in some Write-Output to show what's happening. Your loop needs to be something like `Import-Csv $csv | % { Write-Output "Moving $($_.Username)" ; $src="\\filearch1\$($_.Username)" ; $dst = "C:\B\$($_.Username)" ; robocopy ....... }`

Comment: Thankyou for this response, it allows me to run the script but displays the following error: ERROR 161 (0x000000A1) Getting File System Type of Source \\filearch1\
The specified path is invalid.

Comment: I don't know the name of your fileserver, shares, or where user home folders are located and want to be moved. As the error suggests the path is wrong. Update your script in your original question or we won't be able to help much more.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the reply, ive updated the script and this seems to run ok. I was now looking to make make some additions to the script by including "changing the homedrive path for AD users to c:\c\users and setting the old home path to read only. Could someone please help with this?